# Вывод определенного количества символов PHP

Tags: php, html

Привет. Есть запись которая выводит определенное количество символов

```
<?php echo (strlen($description) > 300 ? utf8_substr(strip_tags(html_entity_decode($description, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')), 0, 100) . '..' : $description); ?>
```

Как сделать, чтобы выводилось любое количество символов до первого абзаца (тэга p или br)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

так вы разобьете строку по концам абзаца или переводу строк с сохранением их в тексте

```
$arr = preg_split('/(<\/p>|<br>)\K/', $str);
```

а теперь насчитывайте, столько элементов массива по длине не превышают лимит,  и объедините

```
 $str = implode('', array_slice($arr, 0, нужное кол-во));
```

---

```
$limit = 30;
$str = '<p>khkjhkjh</p><p>sdkfhd<br>kjfhdk';
$arr = preg_split('/(<\/p>|<br>)\K/', $str); 

$lens = array_map('strlen',$arr);
$i = 0;
$sum = 0;
for($i = 0; $i < count($arr);$i++)
  if(($sum += strlen($arr[$i])) > $limit) break;
echo implode('', array_slice($arr, 0, $i));
```

Comment: Я в пхп полный 0, поэтому и спросил. Можно полный код если не сложно?

Comment: обновил ответ - смотрите

Comment: Спасибо большое!